# Google Adsense on Joomla = Very Slow Website

Tags: joomla-2.5

I'm loading three ads from Google Adsense in my Joomla website but I noticed since I did this, my website is very slower. Ads are loaded asynchronously. I tried also using the synchronous code (from google adsense page) but nothing changes.

Is there a way to speed up this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is no difference between the synchronous and the asynchronous code then the slowness of your site is likely to be related to something else. Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: I am on Hostgator Sharing Plan. My website is fast as a rocket if I do not use Google Adsense but, of course, I need Google Ads. The only fix I found is using Rocket Loader (from Cloudflare) but it's buggy. Sometimes Ads aren't showing if I use Rocket Loader (it automatically asynchronously loads all my js files but it's a beta feature of Cloudflare).

Comment: The fact that asynch still slowed down your site is really weird. Can you provide the code you were using prior to using Rocket Loader(both synch and asynch)? Also please tell us in detail how you implemented it.IE, did you put the code in a custom HTML module or in the template etc.

Comment: The fact that ads don't always load when using Rocket Loader is likely a separate problem. Did you find that ads didn't always load when you used the original adsense implementations?

Comment: No, no.. my ads ALWAYS work if I do not use Rocket Loader. But Rocket Loader should be the best solution to make my website the fastest possible but It's buggy. I am starting thinking all the speed problems of my website are related to javascript files.

Comment: I recommend you install firebug then go to network and see exactly what is causing the slow load.

Comment: DomContentLoaded +4.33s and Load Event +9.57s at "Get mywebsite.com". Size: 68.2 KB, Wait Time 2,91s and Total time= 3,05s

Comment: The most of time is at "Waiting Time" if I hover on the first requests

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to speed how Google Adsense works. It's an external system that gets matching ads based on your site.

I'm not 100% sure about this but, logically, the better your SEO, the easier it will be for Adsense to retrieve relevant ads, thus if you have a new site, I would suggest making SEO improvements a main task.

For standard site optimisation to help speed us the process of the loading times, you may want to consider Caching your assets with something like [JCE Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jch-optimize)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, lodder. I am already using JCH Optimize but this seems not to fix my problems. I can't combine js files because I have problems with it (some components don't work) so i'm just combining css files this is the only benefit I can have from JCH Optimize. I also discovered JCH Optimize increase my TTFB for non-cached pages. Is it normal?

Comment: I'm not a major expert on all the ins and outs, but I would have thought this would increase a little as the server has to perform additional tasks before the site is loaded.